# Python turning ints into floats (Postgres database)

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

What is the best way to avoid this error?

> DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "669068424.0" CONTEXT: 
>   COPY sequence_raw, line 2, column id: "669068424.0"

I created a table using pgadmin which specified the data type for each column. I then read the data in with pandas and do some processing. I could explicitly provide a list of columns and say that they are .astype(int), but is that necessary?

I understand that the reason that there is a .0 after the integers is because there are NaNs in the data so they are turned into floats instead of integers. What is the best way to work around this? I saw on the pre-release of pandas 0.19 that there is better handling of sparse data, is this covered by any chance?

```
def process_file(conn, table_name, file_object):
    fake_conn = pg_engine.raw_connection()
    fake_cur = fake_conn.cursor()
    fake_cur.copy_expert(sql=to_sql % table_name, file=file_object)
    fake_conn.commit()
    fake_cur.close()


df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=query.format(**params), con=engine)
df.to_csv('../raw/temp_sequence.csv', index=False)
df = open('../raw/temp_sequence.csv')
process_file(conn=pg_engine, table_name='sequence_raw', file_object=df)
```

Comment: So you have a table with a `float` column but you want to export it to csv as an int column? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: They are all ints (number of seconds). However, there are rows with NULLs. Python or pandas makes those columns into floats because it doesn't handle NaN integers. I need to fillna with 0 in order for the column to be recognized as an integer (this seems like a waste, I get about 2 million rows per day and a lot of the rows have blanks).

Comment: It's still quite unclear what your exact situation is. Let me see if I understand correctly. You created a table manually with an `int` column, but when you try to export it to a CSV you somehow get a `float` column back?

Comment: Yes, if an integer column has a blank in it then that column is converted to float64. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html. I am trying to find the most efficient workaround. Do I fill the blanks with 0 and then explicitly convert to int? Do I change the columns in Postgres to numeric instead? Is there a better way?

Comment: I see; it's the round-trip to CSV that mangles the data. Have you tried specifying `float_format` argument for [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to remove the decimal places?

Comment: No, let me look into that. If it is something as simple as that then it would be great.

Comment: It worked. I tried float_format='%.0f' and float_format='%g', I am not sure which one is better to use though. I obviously only want to do this if all of my columns are actually integers so I do not accidentally mess up numeric columns with intentional decimals. You can answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `float_format` parameter for `to_csv` to specify the format of the floats in the CSV:

```
df.to_csv('../raw/temp_sequence.csv', index=False, float_format="%d")
```